# What is Dr. Kibner wearing on his hand (and why)?

Tags: body-snatchers

In the classic Invasion of the Body Snatchers (1978), Leonard Nimoy's character; Professor David Kibner is generally seen wearing a sort of leather half-glove.

I've seen several articles stating that he wore it to "*[look distinctive](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077745/trivia)*" but is there any sort of deeper meaning to it within the story itself? What is the back-story behind it?

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's a restrainer to prevent him from doing the Vulcan Salute.  See, just to make absolutely sure, he stuck another finger between the two that are normally together in the salute.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - You have my +1 for lateral thinking.

Comment: Hopefully some folks that are good at ***literal*** thinking will happen by soon.  I'm only good at the other kind.  :P

Comment: "Oh no, it's just that they're terribly comfortable. I think everyone will be wearing them in the future."

Comment: I'm glad this question was asked, as I asked it myself during the live-chat viewing of *Invasion* that we had over at Mos Eisley.

Comment: It's not helpful for the character, but that sort of half glove is sometimes referred to as an "artist glove" or an anti-smudge glove, often worn by artists to reduce the smudging of completed work, and by left-handed writers working in ink since writing left-to-right can involve the heel of your hand drifting over the letters you just wrote.

Comment: Huh... and apparently that sort of half glove is more recent than I thought? https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2891254/Left-handed-sick-smudging-writing-s-GLOVE-stops-dragging-ink-paper.html

Comment: Possibly influenced by Dr Strangelove, and Metropolis. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilHand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the OP mentions in the question, there are plenty of out-of-universe statements regarding the glove, such as this one from Nimoy himself:

> **NIMOY:** We were looking for something that the character could wear that was distinctive and immediately recognizable. I got the idea from a friend who had a badly burned hand and wore the leather covering.

([Source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/liveonline/02/special/entertainment/sp_entertainment_nimoy110602.htm))

But as for in-universe reasons for wearing the glove, I cannot find a canon source that explains this.

Given the lack of information, I will offer my own speculation on the "deeper meaning" of the glove.

As Nimoy recounted, the original purpose of the semi-glove was to ***conceal*** (namely, his friend's burn) rather than to, say, keep the hand warm.

From this, I suspect that the deeper meaning of the glove — if there is one — is that it points to the fact that Dr. Kibner is ***concealing*** something.  (And of course, he is.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, given that Leonard Nimoy is a famous Jewish man and it is on the correct hand for a [tefillin or phylactery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin).

It seems more likely than not he was expressing a part of himself that would have been rarely seen in that era of film. That he is a doctor in New York just makes it more likely that him wearing something like that is no big deal except for the time period in which the film was made. The fact is I noticed it instantly for that reason and truthfully want one. It is flat and simple not a big bulky box. While I understand what was said by Nimoy himself that was the feeling and image that stuck in my mind. It was to the point where someone who watched the movie with me knowing my shared religion suggested I craft one out crocheted string where I could easily write said required elements on parchment place it in between webbing and create my own version inspired by said famous man's outspokenness. While it truly may not have been this representation it still fits with how I express myself within that realm of thought and it still inspires me to think that.

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to add the answer to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Praxis, Nimoy said that he wanted to choose something that the doctor might legitimately wear. One possibility provided, courtesy of Nimoy's friend, was concealing a burn, but another likely case is a "smudge glove", a device which has been in use since antiquity by artists and academics. When drawing or writing, particularly for someone who is left-handed, there is a tendency for the side of the hand to trail along the paper, and making contact with the ink or graphite. This has the effect of both potentially smudging what you are writing, and also leaving you with a stain on your hand. To help prevent this, it's not uncommon to wear a half-glove that can glide along the surface. It is possible that Dr. Kibner owns the glove for that very purpose.

More recently, this sort of glove is commonly used for digital tablets, but according to a comment on my query on the Graphic Design SE, [they have been in use at least since the early Disney animator days](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/162856/is-the-use-of-a-half-glove-to-reduce-left-hand-smudging-a-recent-invention).

> Not really surprising. Their use is so ubiquitous that finding the first use would be challenging. Like finding the inventor of the bucket. :) You may find a first reference.. but inventor is another matter. I can say, from personal experience, I purchased my first smudge glove in the early 1980s... well before 2010. And it was not a "new" thing at the time. You can find photos of Disney animators in the 50s using smudge gloves.

Comment: Is Kibner left-handed?

Comment: Leonard Nimoy was. Not certain if Kibner was. Checking for film clips.